# Datatable query using name rather than username

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-5.1, laravel-datatables

I have a project where we don't store the name of a user and just use their username for everything.

I cam across a package called [Ticketit](https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit) which is a helpdesk ticketing system for Laravel.

The package uses the name of users for everything and so this caused a few errors. I have a `getNameAttribute()` accessor on my `User` model and so for the most part this satisfies the package, however there were some places that explicitly called `name` in Eloquent `::lists()` queries.

For these I manually replaced `name` with `username` inside [my own fork of this repo](https://github.com/jryd/ticketit/tree/dev-username), and have this linked up to my project.

The datatable loads as expected on the page, but when I try to sort by any of the other columns or run a search inside it I get 500 errors in my Network tab of developer tools.

Previewing the response shows this:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 662:
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `ticketit` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `ticketit`.`user_id` inner join `ticketit_statuses` on `ticketit_statuses`.`id` = `ticketit`.`status_id` inner join `ticketit_priorities` on `ticketit_priorities`.`id` = `ticketit`.`priority_id` inner join `ticketit_categories` on `ticketit_categories`.`id` = `ticketit`.`category_id` where `completed_at` is null and (LOWER(`ticketit`.`id`) LIKE %%h%% or LOWER(`subject`) LIKE %%h%% or LOWER(`ticketit_statuses`.`name`) LIKE %%h%% or LOWER(`ticketit`.`updated_at`) LIKE %%h%% or LOWER(`users`.`name`) LIKE %%h%% or LOWER(`ticketit_priorities`.`name`) LIKE %%h%% or LOWER(`users`.`name`) LIKE %%h%% or LOWER(`ticketit_categories`.`name`) LIKE %%h%%)) count_row_table)

Following the route this posts to, I get to `TicketController@data`. In the original package this is:

```
public function data(Datatables $datatables, $complete = false)
    {
        $user = $this->agent->find(auth()->user()->id);
        if ($user->isAdmin()) {
            if ($complete) {
                $collection = Ticket::complete();
            } else {
                $collection = Ticket::active();
            }
        } elseif ($user->isAgent()) {
            if ($complete) {
                $collection = Ticket::complete()->agentUserTickets($user->id);
            } else {
                $collection = Ticket::active()->agentUserTickets($user->id);
            }
        } else {
            if ($complete) {
                $collection = Ticket::userTickets($user->id)->complete();
            } else {
                $collection = Ticket::userTickets($user->id)->active();
            }
        }
        $collection
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ticketit.user_id')
            ->join('ticketit_statuses', 'ticketit_statuses.id', '=', 'ticketit.status_id')
            ->join('ticketit_priorities', 'ticketit_priorities.id', '=', 'ticketit.priority_id')
            ->join('ticketit_categories', 'ticketit_categories.id', '=', 'ticketit.category_id')
            ->select([
                'ticketit.id',
                'ticketit.subject AS subject',
                'ticketit_statuses.name AS status',
                'ticketit_statuses.color AS color_status',
                'ticketit_priorities.color AS color_priority',
                'ticketit_categories.color AS color_category',
                'ticketit.id AS agent',
                'ticketit.updated_at AS updated_at',
                'ticketit_priorities.name AS priority',
                'users.name AS owner',
                'ticketit.agent_id',
                'ticketit_categories.name AS category',
            ]);
        $collection = $datatables->of($collection);
        $this->renderTicketTable($collection);
        $collection->editColumn('updated_at', '{!! \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $updated_at)->diffForHumans() !!}');
        return $collection->make(true);
    }
```

Which I have edited to this in my fork:

```
public function data(Datatables $datatables, $complete = false)
    {
        $user = $this->agent->find(auth()->user()->id);
        if ($user->isAdmin()) {
            if ($complete) {
                $collection = Ticket::complete();
            } else {
                $collection = Ticket::active();
            }
        } elseif ($user->isAgent()) {
            if ($complete) {
                $collection = Ticket::complete()->agentUserTickets($user->id);
            } else {
                $collection = Ticket::active()->agentUserTickets($user->id);
            }
        } else {
            if ($complete) {
                $collection = Ticket::userTickets($user->id)->complete();
            } else {
                $collection = Ticket::userTickets($user->id)->active();
            }
        }
        $collection
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ticketit.user_id')
            ->join('ticketit_statuses', 'ticketit_statuses.id', '=', 'ticketit.status_id')
            ->join('ticketit_priorities', 'ticketit_priorities.id', '=', 'ticketit.priority_id')
            ->join('ticketit_categories', 'ticketit_categories.id', '=', 'ticketit.category_id')
            ->select([
                'ticketit.id',
                'ticketit.subject AS subject',
                'ticketit_statuses.name AS status',
                'ticketit_statuses.color AS color_status',
                'ticketit_priorities.color AS color_priority',
                'ticketit_categories.color AS color_category',
                'ticketit.id AS agent',
                'ticketit.updated_at AS updated_at',
                'ticketit_priorities.name AS priority',
                'users.username AS owner',
                'ticketit.agent_id',
                'ticketit_categories.name AS category',
            ]);
        $collection = $datatables->of($collection);
        $this->renderTicketTable($collection);
        $collection->editColumn('updated_at', '{!! \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $updated_at)->diffForHumans() !!}');
        return $collection->make(true);
    }
```

With this I have changed the `users.name` to `users.username`, but this isn't fixing the issue for me.

Can anyone help me figure out why, or what else I need to change as I haven't had any luck figuring out where else I need to change this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll drive yourself nuts trying to edit all the places where the 3rd-party code tries to access `name`.  My suggestion is to fix at the root rather than patch in many places:

1. Create a new `name` column in `users` table
2. Fill that column with the values in the `username` column

eg queries:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD COLUMN `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL AFTER `username`; 
UPDATE `users` SET `name` = `username`;
```

Now your DB will have the schema that your plugin expects.

Comment: I could do this, but to me this seems more of a patch than a root fix. As I said, the accessor solves the request for `name` in 99% of cases. There's only been 3 cases so far where it is looking explicitly for `name` and I've changed these to username. I'm just trying to figure out where it is getting that query for `name` from now and it will work completely. I will use this if I absolutely have to, it just seems pointless to have to do it for the sake of one package.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was in the initialisation of the DataTable where it was calling `users.name` rather than `users.username`.

After updating this, clearing the views cache `php artisan view:clear` it all worked fine!